# Integrate Facebook Audience Network and AdMob together?

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I have integrated Facebook Audience Network in my Android application but I am getting a very poor fill rate, around 40%.

I am thinking about integrating AdMob along side Facebook Audience Network, for example when the Facebook Audience Network fails to fill an ad I'd show an AdMob ad.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You can use mediation for this. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Facebook Audience Network ad fails to load present an AdMob ad.

> Now that you have the basic code running, it's recommended that you use the `AdListener` to get notified when the ad fails to load so you could hide the banner unit. In the same way, you can add it back when it was loaded:

via [**Adding Ad Banners to your Android app**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/banner)